# Why does app activation link fail to launch app on android 4.x but not on 2.x

Tags: android, intentfilter

I am trying to implement Custom URL Scheme on my Android App. Here is the complete activity flow:

Step 1: User downloads the app on the device

Step 2: User installs the app on the device

Step 3: User sign’s up for the App from the sign up page.

Step 4: Once sign up/registration is completed, then web server sends an email to the user for activating the account

Step 5: User needs to open the activation email from the web browser or email app from an
Android phone

Step 6: When the user clicks on the activation link in the email, the system should perform the following steps:

6.a User gets activated through the URL

6.b System verifies whether the request is coming from computer or mobile device (Java script code in browser is performing this check)

6.c If the user is using mobile device and device OS is Android then the activation process should open the installed app after activation

Problem

The above solution is working for Android OS version 2.x but not working for the OS version 4.x The problem occurs if the user clicks on the activation link in the email app of Android 4.0 device. Upon activation, user is being redirected to the page and mobile browser returns error message ‘Web page can’t be found’

Implementation:

I defined custom URL Scheme in the manifest of the app for Log In screen activity definition. Once url appnameURLScheme://appname is invoked from the browser, it launches the login screen of the app and bring the app on the forefront by putting the browser in back ground.

Here is the Manifest:

```
<activity
   android:name=".AppNameScreen"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity
   android:name=".LoginScreen"
   android:screenOrientation="portrait"
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
   <intent-filter>
      <data
      android:host="AppName"
      android:scheme="AppNameURLScheme" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
         <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
         <category
            android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```